# Sending mail using Codeigniter and localhost with XAMPP in Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I've changed the XAMPP's php.ini "sendmail_path = '/usr/bin/msmtp -t'" but I still get this error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP x66sm53059629pfb.86 - gsmtp

hello: 250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [203.177.142.78]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 x66sm53059629pfb.86 - gsmtp
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 07:21:37 +0200
From: "juan dela cruz" <sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com>
To: sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Email=20Testing?=
Reply-To: <sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com>
X-Sender: sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <57c517e10e70b@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Email is working great.
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
function index(){
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' =>'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxx'
            );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com', 'some name');
        $this->email->to('sampleticketdaddress@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject("Email Testing");
        $this->email->message('Email is working great.');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "Email has been sent.";
        }
        else 
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

My password is correct so I think the issue is not there. Can you please tell me where I'm wrong or what else I need to do to make this code work in Ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: Hi frd, please do not change directly in php.ini file , first of all use php mail() function and send parameter like from , to , body etc , than check it to send email or not .

Comment: Okay. I'll return the configurations in my php.ini to what it was before. Can you please tell me what to do next? Thank you.

Comment: if your mail function is working than please do not changes your php.ini file , it means your codeigniter configuration some how to mistake .

Comment: I wouldn't know if my mail function is correct since I cannot send an email using my code above.

Comment: dear i am asking to check php mail function not a your code , php mail function is provide to php enbuilt function  .please search them your side

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  I am really new at this. I ran this code: ""Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v myEmail@gmail.com" and I think it is working right because it tried connecting to gmail. I don't know if this is what you mean though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',// your mail name
'smtp_pass' => '*****',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
 'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

then

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Mail Settings in XAMPP(Impotent)

```
$this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');//your mail address and name
$this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); //receiver mail

$this->email->subject('testing');
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send(); //sending mail
```

Configuration in sendmail.ini

path  c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
in php.ini
```

pathc:\xampp\xampp\php\php.ini

[mail function]

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. Can you give me the path for those please? Specially the sendmail_path.

Comment: what r u using xampp or lampp ?

Comment: I am using XAMPP Sir.